# SSIS Errors for simple CSV Data Flow

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container

Sorry to darken your day with my troubles, but SSIS has broken me!  I am new to SSIS and I just seem to be misunderstanding it.

For background:  I have a few versions of a basic package that includes a Foreach Loop container and a Data Flow with a few Derived Columns that imports CSV files into a SQL Server Staging table.  It is very straightforward and does include an Execute SQL task and a File Move but those work fine.  The issues are with the Foreach loop and the Data Flow.

I have one version of this package (let’s call it “A”) that seemed to be working fine.  It would process multiple files in a folder, insert records into the staging table, properly execute the SQL Statements, and move the files to Archive.  Everything seemed fine until I carefully QA’d the process.  Turns out it was duplicating the data from one file, and never importing the data from a second Source File!  Yet, the second/dupe round of data included the Source Filename (via a derived column) of the second file (but the data from the first).  So it looked like I had successfully processed BOTH files until I looked at the actual data and saw that none of the values from the second source file were ever written to the Staging table.

Once I discovered this, I figured that the problem was in the Foreach loop and how I setup the different file path & name variables.  So, I decided to try to make a new version of the package.  I started by copying package A and created package B.  In B, I deleted the Source Connection manager and created a new Connection Manager along with all new file & path variables.  I then tried to cleanup/fix/replace various elements in my Data Flow and Foreach loop.  In the process, I discovered that the Advanced Mappings from A – which DID work – were virtually all setup as String (even the Currency and Date columns).  That did not seem right, so I modified each source money column by changing to data type Currency, and changed each date-related column to data type Date.

What followed has been dozens and dozens of Errors and I cannot get Package B to run.  I have even changed all of the B data types back to String (mirroring the setup in Package A which DID work).  But, still no joy.

This leads me to ask a few questions to those of you smarter than I:

1)  Why can’t SSIS interpret Source CSV data using the proper data type?  I.e. why do I need to set every Input column as a STRING when some columns are clearly & completely Numeric, Currency or Dates?  (Yes, the Source CSV files are VERY clean – most don’t even have NULLS)

a.  When I do change the Advanced mapping for a date-related Source column to Date, I get the ever present error message:  [Flat File Source [30]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Settle Date" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

2)  When I reset the data types back to String in package B, I still get errors – usually Truncation errors (and Yes – I have adjusted the length to 250 in one of these columns).
a.  Error Message:  "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
b.  When I reset the Mappings to ignore the column (as a test), it throws a similar error at the next column.

3)  Any ideas why Package A would dupe a file’s data and not process the second file, yet throw no errors and move both to Archive?

4)  Why does the Data Viewer appear to have parsing errors (it shows data in the wrong columns) but when you use the Copy data feature in the data viewer and paste it into Excel, all of the data lines up perfectly?

5)  Are there any tips & tricks that a rookie SSIS user needs to understand and which might not be apparent through the documentation and searching web articles as well as this site?

I can provide further details if they will help, but these packages are really very simple and should not be causing me this much frustration.

THANKS for any insights.

DGP

Comment: Do all the files in the folder have the exact same columns, with the exact same datatypes, in the exact same order?

Answer (score 0):

Wow seems like you have a lot of ssis issues... I think the reason for the same file being extracted is because of the the way your 'variable mappings' is defined.

Have you had a look and followed this guide:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/

Hope this helps.

Shaheen

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tab & Shaheen,

To all SSIS rookies - please learn from my mistakes!

It appears that my issue was actually in how I identified the TEXT QUALIFIER in the Connection Manager.  I had entered     ""     and that was causing problems with how my columns were being parsed.  The parsing issues caused unexpected values to appear in some of the columns and that was causing the errors in the package.

When I tried changing the the Text Qualifier to only ONE double quote - "  - the whole thing worked!

As I mentioned - and as Shaheen suspected - my initial issues with the duplicate processing was probably due to how I setup the foreach loop.  I had already fixed that, bit was still getting errors until I fixed the Text Qualifier.

I have only tested it a few times but it looks like that was the issue.

Thanks for the contributions.

DGP

Comment: The lesson to learn is: try not to be overwhelmed. When troubleshooting, take it back to basics - create a brand new package that does only one thing and confirm that it works. SSIS can be overwhelming with its verbose errors and it is extremely picky about metadata and datatypes, but for good reason - it saves a lot of issues further down the line.